# Как сделать проверку счета xrp?

Tags: python, json, requests

Эх, сделала простой скрипт на селене не поможете в чем проблема?

Выбрала данный сайт для виджета проверки своего баланса.

```
import json
import requests
 def prov_req():
        adr = "rpKqEptZFnnBweW4bx28RX8cAtgRbq3CCC"
        adr2 = "rhCBVSr1hzRCoN6qDmLcUrmnEwkfAPcwsP"
   
        getbalanceurl = str('https://bithomp.com/api/v2/address/' + str(adr2))
        balance = requests.get(getbalanceurl)
        jsonresponse = json.loads(balance.text)
        df = jsonresponse['data']['address'] + ':balance:' + jsonresponse['data']['confirmed_balance']
        print(df)

    prov_req()
Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?
```

Comment: Что за библиотека `reqvests`? Знаю `requests`

Comment: В `getbalanceurl` вызывать `str` не нужно: `getbalanceurl = 'https://bithomp.com/api/v2/address/' + adr2`. И не должна на такой адрес происходить ошибка `Invalid URL ''`, у вас точно тот код из вопроса вызывается? Вместо текста ошибки лучше добавлять трассу стека (это куча текста, идущая вместе с текстом ошибки). Для селениума лучше отдельный вопрос сделать, т.к. разные вещи

Comment: Ок,поправила ,я пока разбираюсь и учусь пользоватца json.А как правельно?Хотя бы где почитать можно примеры для джейсон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал код, но судя по ошибке `{'error': 'errors.token.required'}` нужно в запросе передавать токен.

Для этого:

- [Смотрите в API того сайта](https://docs.bithomp.com/#authentication), чтобы получить токен (скорее всего понадобится зарегистрироваться на сайте, чтобы получить его)
- Токен нужно передавать в запросе (это `HTTP` заголовок `x-bithomp-token`)

Код:

```
import requests

addr2 = "rhCBVSr1hzRCoN6qDmLcUrmnEwkfAPcwsP"
get_balance_url = 'https://bithomp.com/api/v2/address/' + addr2

headers = {
    'x-bithomp-token': '<ваш токен>',
}

rs = requests.get(get_balance_url, headers=headers)
data = rs.json()
print(data)
# {'error': 'errors.token.required'}

# df = data['data']['address'] + ':balance:' + data['data']['confirmed_balance']
# print(df)
```

---

Кст, в API по https://bithomp.com/api/v2/address/ нет в ответе ключа `data` и `confirmed_balance`, пример JSON, что вернется:

```
{
  "address": "rPEPPER7kfTD9w2To4CQk6UCfuHM9c6GDY",
  "xAddress": "XV5sbjUmgPpvXv4ixFWZ5ptAYZ6PD2gYsjNFQLKYW33DzBm",
  "inception": 1513126312,
  "username": "xrptipbot",
  "service": {
    "name": "XRP Tip Bot",
    "domain": "xrptipbot.com",
    "socialAccounts": {
      "twitter": "xrptipbot"
    }
  },
  "forensic": 0,
  "verifiedDomain": "xrptipbot.com",
  "parent": {
    "address": "rDsbeomae4FXwgQTJp9Rs64Qg9vDiTCdBv",
    "xAddress": "XV3oNHx95sqdCkTDCBCVsVeuBmvh2du1vBfJR24EqdgwHDW",
    "inception": 1481884572,
    "service": {
      "name": "Bitstamp",
      "domain": "bitstamp.net",
      "socialAccounts": {
        "twitter": "Bitstamp",
        "facebook": "Bitstamp"
      }
    },
    "forensic": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Окей ,посмотрю .Как насчет селениума пробую спарсить блок мне выдает ошибку:(

Comment: @аленакарпенко, лучше сделайте отдельный вопрос и в нем минимальный пример, показывающий проблему :)

Comment: ок,тогда подправлю и задам второй вопрос.